# Google Apps Script to add a Validation Dropdown automatically based on cell value

Tags: arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to add a Validation dropdown everywhere a cell value is "test" in a specific range.

I thought I was close, but I think I'm running into an issue with the arrays, I believe.

Really struggling with this one, hoping it's a small tweak someone might see:

```
function setValueToEmptyCell(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const valuesFlat = sheet.getRange('a1:c10').getValues().flat();
  //Empty array to store the output values;
  const output = [];

  valuesFlat.forEach(row => {
    if(row == 'test'){
      (SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
      .setAllowInvalid(true)
      .requireValueInRange(sheet.getRange('$H1:H3'), true)
      .build());
    } else {
      output.push([row])
    }
  })

  //Because we have stored the original value we overwrite the whole range with the 'new' values
  sheet.getRange('a1:c10').setValues(output);
}
```

This is the error I'm seeing:

> 1:54:51 AM    Notice  Execution started
> 1:54:52 AM    Error    Exception: The
> number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the
> range. The data has 7 but the range has 10.

Comment: It's not clear what the script should do.  What is the purpose of ` output.push([row])` and  `sheet.getRange('a1:c10').setValues(output);`? Besides clarifying this, please also add some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- For the cells "A1:C10", when the cell value is `test`, you want to put a dropdown list of `SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInRange(sheet.getRange('$H1:H3'), true).build()`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the rows and columns cannot be parsed by `flat()` of `const valuesFlat = sheet.getRange('a1:c10').getValues().flat();`.
- `(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInRange(sheet.getRange('$H1:H3'), true).build())` is not used.
- In order to put the dropdown list, `setDataValidations(rules)` is used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function setValueToEmptyCell() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = sheet.getRange('a1:c10');
  const valuesFlat = range.getValues();
  const output = [];
  valuesFlat.forEach(row => {
    const temp = [];
    row.forEach(col => {
      if (col == 'test') {
        temp.push(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
          .setAllowInvalid(true)
          .requireValueInRange(sheet.getRange('$H1:H3'), true)
          .build());
      } else {
        temp.push(null);
      }
    });
    output.push(temp);
  });
  range.setDataValidations(output);
  
  // range.createTextFinder("test").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
}
```

- When this script is run, when the cell value of "A1:C10" is `test`, a dropdown list of `SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInRange(sheet.getRange('$H1:H3'), true).build()` is put.
- If you want to remove `test` from the cell value after the dropdown list was put, please use `range.createTextFinder("test").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");`.

#### Reference:

- [setDataValidations(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules)